# Windows 10 - re-install shows no networks

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking

I ran out of options when I was stuck in a reboot cycle ending in the nicer version of the old BSOD.

Long story short, I did I "refresh" install with the option to keep my files.   I did every other thing I could before that (25+ years working with MS tech).

It worked.   Windows boots back into the original environment.   Manufacturer's crap and all.

When I open my wireless network connections it's empty.

Uninstall McAfee and reboot.

EMPTY.

How can I get this machine back on the internet?

I would go into the gory command - line details but I'm on my phone now due to this.

Comment: Have you visited the manufacturers website and download and installed all the drivers? Obviously using another computer and a flash drive. It should be apparent in device manager if there are drivers missing. You need to try updating then anyways to try to fix this. Did you try hard wiring he system?

Comment: Forgot to ask, is this a laptop? Maybe the wireless switch is off?

Comment: "Windows boots back into the original environment. Manufacturer's crap and all." - This means younused Reset not Refresh.

Comment: It is a laptop.  There is no distinct wireless switch, only the option for Airplane Mode which is off.  I did "keep my files" reset option.  Everything looks ok outside of being unable to see any wireless networks. See my comment to the answer bellow regarding odd Safe Mode behavior.  Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

In general, wireless adapter driver will be lost after system reinstall, in order to make wireless adapter works again, we need to reinstall its driver. Open Device Manager to check wireless adapter’s state.

Since your computer is unable to connect to Internet now, use manufacturer driver installation disk to install wireless adapter driver, or connect to a wired network at first, then download driver from manufacturer website.

If cannot connect to Internet by any way, copy driver installation package from other computer via an USB drive, then install it on your computer.

Please note, if we want to reinstall system, backup driver in advance.

Regards

Comment: The strange thing is the drivers are fine when I boot normally (Qualcomm).  I even pointed them for Ann update to my manufacturer's original driver store and it says they are "latest".  However, if I boot into Safe Mode, the driver is flagged with an exclamation mark.   But only in Safe Mode!